# Payum : What is the difference between status?

Tags: payum

Where I can find informations on the status of return of payment?
For "canceled" and "failed", it's ok. But what is the difference between "captured", "authorized", "suspended" and "pending". What does it mean for paypal ?
Thanks

Comment: The statuses should be pretty much self explained. Accoding to capture vs authorize in terms of Paypal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/auth-capture/

Comment: Pending means the payment is in progress, In case paypal it maybe mutli currency issue, where buyer has to manually decide what to do with moneys.

Comment: suspended is not used for paypal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of Paypal payment status :

**Canceled_Reversal**: A reversal has been canceled. For example, you won a dispute with the customer, and the funds for the transaction that was reversed have been returned to you.

**Completed**: The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance.

**Created**: A German ELV payment is made using Express Checkout.

**Denied**: You denied the payment. This happens only if the payment was previously pending because of possible reasons described for the pending_reason variable or the Fraud_Management_Filters_x variable.

**Expired**: This authorization has expired and cannot be captured.

**Failed**: The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was made from your customer’s bank account.

**Pending**: The payment is pending. See pending_reason for more information.

**Refunded**: You refunded the payment.

**Reversed**: A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of reversal. The funds have been removed from your account balance and returned to the buyer. The reason for the reversal is specified in the ReasonCode element.
Processed: A payment has been accepted.
Voided: This authorization has been voided.

---

Payum Status :

**captured** : The payment process has been initialized.

**authorized** : Is equal to the **Completed** PP payment status.

**suspended** : ? (Community action needed)

**pending** : Is equal to the **Pending** PP payment status.